# Conformal mapping of upper half of unit circle to unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

How do I find conformal mapping that transforms D={z: abs(z)<1 & Im(z)>0} int D'={w: abs(w)<1}

And what is generally approach to this type of problem? Should I always try to find bilinear transformation?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is a bilinear transformation?

Comment: @LeeMosher: It is another name for $\dfrac{az+b}{cz+d}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: There's a standard map of the unit disc to the right half plane. This will take the upper half disc to the first quadrant. Now square it to get the upper half plane, ...

Comment: Ok, thank you. But what if it was given something harder for D', is there maybe some approach to get system of equations?